# Windows Phone 8 System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, video-streaming, smooth-streaming-player

Here's the problem-

I am creating a windows phone 8 app with video streaming capabilities.
I am using player framework from-

http://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%3A%20WP8%20Smooth%20Streaming%20Player

On following their steps, I get this exception

```
$exception  {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Windows.Media.DrmException: 1001
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MediaElement_SetMediaStreamSource(MediaElement mediaElement, Int32 mediaStreamerId)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement.SetSource(MediaStreamSource mediaStreamSource)
   at Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.SmoothStreamingMediaElement.au(Uri A_0)
   at Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.SmoothStreamingMediaElement.a3(Uri A_0, Uri A_1)
   at Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.SmoothStreamingMediaElement.a7(DependencyObject A_0, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs A_1)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.SmoothStreamingMediaElement.set_SmoothStreamingSource(Uri value)
   at Microsoft.PlayerFramework.Adaptive.SmoothStreamingMediaElementWrapper.Microsoft.PlayerFramework.IMediaElement.set_Source(Uri value)
   at Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer.<>c__DisplayClass93.<set__Source>b__92()
   at Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer.RegisterApplyTemplateAction(Action action)
   at Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer.set__Source(Uri value)
   at Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer.LoadSource(MediaLoadingInstruction loadingInstruction)
   at Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer.<>c__DisplayClass2e.<<SetSource>b__2c>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()}    System.Exception {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}
```

I do not get the above exception if I follow the same steps when creating a new application from scratch.
I have also used it before and it works fine.

if I remove the reference to Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.dll,
then I get this Exception

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module. and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Unhandled Exception: System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgsCould not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming, Version=1.1.837.146, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.   at Microsoft.PlayerFramework.Adaptive.AdaptivePlugin.get_MediaElement()
   at Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer.GetTemplateChildren()
   at Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer.<OnApplyTemplate>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)
The program '[3720] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

So it seems like I am having some conflicting references (thats what I think)

How can I resolve this problem??

All help appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry

Bad question.

There were capabilities missing from the manifest file of the app.